# Running two sites on two different webservers under one url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need a solution for following issue:
Now I have two sites on two different webservers e.g. **a.com** and **b.com**

What I want is to have **b** in url  under **a.com** in a way:
**a.com/b**
keeping webserver **b.com** separately, but with working **b** site under **a.com/b**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what webserver are you using ? and in which language are you coding ?

Comment: apache webserver, php

Comment: Simple [proxy settings](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) would do it.

Comment: Post your current vHost containers of both a.com and b.com

Comment: The proxy settings might actually work. Thnx Wrikken. It's something new for me. I'll check pros and cons of such solution. Does anyone have any other ideas?